# Distinguish between messages python3 tcp sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

So I am trying to make an app where a user client would send messages to a server. I want to find a way to distinguish between one message and the next so that I can loop over `sock.recv(1)` until I know the message has ended and save the message, then I can move on to the next message. I might be going at this the wrong way entirely, but I'm not sure how to do this with TCP streams. Right now I just have this for user.py

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("localhost", 1234))
while True:
    resp = someEventThatReturnsAMessage()
    if resp:
        resp += "|"
        sock.send(resp.encode('utf-8'))
```

and this for my server

```
import socket, threading
class Client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.sock = conn
    def recv(self)
        msg = ''
        while True:
            try:
                l = self.sock.recv(1)
                if l.decode('utf-8') == "|":
                    return msg
                if l == b'':
                    return "Terminated"
                msg += l.decode("utf-8")
            except:
                return "Nothing to Receive"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)   
sock.bind(('', 1234))
sock.listen(5)
while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    conn.setBlocking(0)
    threadedClient = Client(conn)
```

The thing is if I ever send an `|` it messes it all up. I dont know what to do.

Comment: You either need a unique separator character (that will not be duplicated by any "payload" message), or you need to specify the size of each message. The latter is often easier to use and more robust (although it may seem more work at first). See this answer for more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51546266/1076479

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from a stream one character at a time is going to be pretty slow. Something you might try is sending one message at a time and then fully reading the stream on the receiving end before sending another message.

Here is some example code you can reference:

```
def read_all_from_connection(self):
    def _read_entire_stream_chunked():
        while True:
            incremental_bytes = self.sock.recv(1024)
            if len(incremental_bytes) == 0:
                return
            yield incremental_bytes
    full_message = b""
    for partial_msg_bytes in _read_entire_stream_chunked():
        full_message += partial_msg_bytes
    self.sock.close()
    return full_message.decode("utf-8")
```

**EDIT:** I did not state this explicitly, but this strategy would be to read a single message per each connection. The performance hit should be negligible, and it may be easier to avoid half-open/hanging connections. If there are performance reasons for wanting to re-use a socket between messages check out: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html instead.

Comment: This is a poor strategy if you want to continue communication beyond a single message; your read function here won't terminate until end-of-file (i.e. when the socket is closed by the peer).

Comment: I will update the answer to state explicitly, I am suggesting to open a new connection for each message.

Comment: A chunk might also break across a multibyte UTF-8 character and the `.decode` would fail.  If it is a single message the `.decode` should happen on the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Since TCP is a byte streaming protocol with no message boundaries, one solution is to wrap the socket in a protocol layer that only sends and receives complete messages.  The following defines a message as "UTF-8 encoded bytes ending in a newline(\n) character":

```
from socket import *

class Socket:
    def __init__(self,s=None):
        '''default create a new socket, or wrap an existing one.
        '''
        self.sock = socket() if s is None else s
        self.buffer = b''

    def connect(self,addr):
        self.sock.connect(addr)

    def bind(self,addr):
        self.sock.bind(addr)

    def listen(self,n):
        self.sock.listen(n)

    def accept(self):
        c,a = self.sock.accept()
        # Wrap the client socket in a Socket.
        return Socket(c),a

    def get_msg(self):
        # Buffer data until a newline is found.
        while b'\n' not in self.buffer:
            data = self.sock.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                return b''
            self.buffer += data
        # split off the message bytes from the buffer.
        msg,_,self.buffer = self.buffer.partition(b'\n')
        return msg.decode()

    def put_msg(self,msg):
        self.sock.sendall(msg.encode() + b'\n')

    def close(self):
        self.sock.close()
```

Use it like this:

```
import threading
import time

From mysocket import Socket

def server():
    s = Socket()
    s.bind(('',8000))
    s.listen(5)

    while True:
        c,a = s.accept()
        print(f'server: {a[0]}:{a[1]} connected')
        while True:
            msg = c.get_msg()
            if not msg:
                break
            print(f'server: {msg}')
            c.put_msg(f'[{msg}]')
        print(f'server: {a[0]}:{a[1]} disconnected')
        c.close()

def client():
    s = Socket()
    s.connect(('localhost',8000))
    s.put_msg('Hello')
    s.put_msg('马克')
    print(f'client: {s.get_msg()}')
    print(f'client: {s.get_msg()}')
    s.close()

t = threading.Thread(target=server,daemon=True)
t.start()
client()
```

Output:

```
server: 127.0.0.1:1354 connected
server: Hello
server: 马克
client: [Hello]
client: [马克]
server: 127.0.0.1:1354 disconnected
```

Comment: This solution breaks when there is a line-feed character within a message.

Comment: @TimothyJannace This is just an example that uses newline to separate messages.  A "line-oriented protocol" where a message ends in a newline.  If you want newlines as part of the message, define a different separator, support escaping the separator, write the length of the message before the message, etc.

Comment: @TimothyJannace A length-based mechanism would check that the buffered data contains, say, at least 4 bytes representing a big-endian integer X, and a total of X+4 bytes representing the complete message, split the length and message off from the buffer, and return the message.  Allowing multiple messages in one connection is also much faster than creating a new connection and closing it after a single message.  Establishing a connection is relatively expensive.

Comment: If you b64encode the contents of each message you could use a line-feed character to delimit messages.

Comment: As far as the speed issue goes:
1. Tcp protocol provides a mechanism for separating messages from one another (ie: the connection itself). So I should simply use that to separate messages and not build another protocol on top of it.
2. If it is not performant enough, I should implement a more robust library that has been de-bugged and performance optimized.

I'm sure #1 is less efficient but I am simply knowing my limits as a developer both in skill and time available. By the way, I did learn a thing or two from your post/comments and upvoted so not to downplay it. :)

Comment: @Tim A real world example is Http protocol. It has a keepalive header the keeps the connection open, but the original implementation closes the connection at each request. I’ve used keepalive to  request and download multiple files and it was orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: My understanding is that in good network conditions it's insignificant to open / close a connection. But it's all relative of course! Appreciate the friendly & thoughtful discussion & excellent code above. Take care.