# Threaded socket doesn't transfer all data using sendall

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I am currently running into an issue where the following code only reads the first 1028 bytes from a socket, and then hangs waiting for more even though the rest has been sent. I thought it could be the code causing the problem, but it only happens when I am receiving data from the client to the server  (which is multi-threaded). When I run the code in reverse (server sending data to client) it runs without an issue.

This is what is currently failing:

**The clients code:**

```
with open(commands[1], "rb") as file:
     data = file.read()

     # Sends the length of the file to the server
     serverSocket.sendall(str(len(data)).encode())


     # Sends the data to the server
     data = file.read(1024)
     while data:
          data = file.read(1024)
          serverSocket.sendall(data)
```

**Along with the server code:**

```
        # Gets the total length of the file
        dataLen = int(clientsocket.recv(1024).decode())
        totalData = ""

        while len(totalData) < dataLen:
            # Reads in and appends the data to the variable
            data = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
            totalData += data
```

**What else have I tried?**
The original code for the client was:

```
with open(commands[1], "rb") as file:
     data = file.read()

     # Sends the length of the file to the server
     serverSocket.sendall(str(len(data)).encode())


     # Sends the data to the server
     serverSocket.sendall(data)
```

Which I changed because I thought there may be an issue with the recv not getting all of the packets from the client, but the client believes that everything was sent.

**Minimum Reproducible Code**:

**SERVER.PY**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, error
from threading import Thread, Lock
from _thread import interrupt_main

import logging
from sys import stdout

from os import makedirs
from pathlib import Path

class Server:

def __init__(self, host, port):

    logging.basicConfig(stream=stdout, level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')

    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.quitVal = False
    self.threads = []
    self.lock = Lock()
    self.sock = None
    self.open()

def open(self):
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
    sock.listen(5)
    self.sock = sock

def listen(self):

    try:
        while self.quitVal != True:
            (clientsocket, address) = self.sock.accept()
            # This creates a threaded connection as this is the choke for the connection
            thread = Thread(target=self.connection, args=(clientsocket, address), daemon=True)
            self.threads.append(thread)
            thread.start()
    except OSError:
        quit()

def connection(self, clientsocket, address):
    while self.quitVal != True:
        # We are going to allow multiple file transfers at one time on a connection
        requestThreads = []          

        # The client innitially sends a command "s<command> [<fileLocation>]"
        data = clientsocket.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")

        data = data.split()
        data[0] = data[0].lower()

        if data[0] == "get":
            thread = Thread(target=self.get, args=(clientsocket, data[1]), daemon=True)
            requestThreads.append(thread)
            thread.start()

        elif data[0] == "put":
            thread = Thread(target=self.put, args=(clientsocket, data[1]), daemon=True)
            requestThreads.append(thread)
            thread.start()
    clientsocket.close()

def get(self, clientsocket, fileLocation):

    # Tries to get the file, and sends it all to the client
    with self.lock:
        try:
            with open(fileLocation, "rb") as file:
                data = file.read()

                # Sends the length of the file to the client
                clientsocket.sendall(str(len(data)).encode())

                # Byte to separate the input from length and file
                response = self.sock.recv(1).decode()

                # Sends the data to the client
                clientsocket.sendall(data)

        except IOError as e:
            print("\nFile doesn't exist")


def put(self, clientsocket, fileLocation):
    # Gets the total length of the file
    with self.lock:
        dataLen = int(clientsocket.recv(1024).decode())
        totalData = ""

        # Gets the total length of the file
        dataLen = int(clientsocket.recv(1024).decode())
        totalData = ""

        # Byte to separate the input from length and file
        clientsocket.sendall("0".encode())

        while len(totalData) < dataLen:
            # Reads in and appends the data to the variable
            data = clientsocket.recv(2048).decode()
            totalData += data

        logging.info(totalData)

server = Server("127.0.0.1", 10002)
server.listen()
```

**CLIENT.PY**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, error
from threading import Thread, Lock
from _thread import interrupt_main

import logging
from sys import stdout

from os import makedirs
from pathlib import Path


class Client:

def __init__(self, host, port):

    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.quitVal = False
    self.sock = self.open()
    self.threads = []
    self.lock = Lock()   

def open(self):
    try:
        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
    except error as err:
        return None
    return sock

def get(self, commands):
    # Sends the request for the file to the server using the main Sock        
    with self.lock:
        command = "GET " + commands[0]
        self.sock.send(command.encode()) 

        dataLen = int(self.sock.recv(1024).decode())
        totalData = ""

        self.sock.sendall("0".encode())


        while len(totalData) < dataLen:
            data = self.sock.recv(2048).decode()
            totalData += data


def put(self, commands):

    with self.lock:
        # Sends the put call command to the server
        command = "PUT " + commands[1]
        self.sock.sendall(command.encode())

        try:
            with open(commands[1], "rb") as file:
                data = file.read()

                # Sends the length of the file to the server
                self.sock.sendall(str(len(data)).encode())

                # Byte to separate the input from length and file
                response = self.sock.recv(1).decode()

                # Sends the data to the server
                self.sock.sendall(data)    
        except IOError as e:
            logging.info("\nFile doesn't exist")

client = Client("127.0.0.1", 10002)
print("foo")
client.get(["foo.txt", "bar.txt"])
client.put(["foo.txt", "bar1.txt"])
```

Comment: Try providing us a [mcve]. Otherwise, there's no way to know how this interacts with your threading code.

Comment: Also, while it may not be the immediate problem you are seeing... you are not imposing any message boundaries. See this answer for a discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51546266/1076479

Comment: 'Client believes that everything was sent' doesn't prove that the client hasn't lost the data. That's the only way this problem can occur.

Comment: @GilHamilton I updated the question to have some code :) The indentation is slightly off because of copy-paste.

Comment: Take a look at the link I posted previously. You cannot rely on a `send(foo)` followed by `send(bar)` on the sending side to match up with `foo=recv(1024)` followed by `bar=recv(1024)` on the other side. That *may* work sometimes, but not others, due to unpredictable timing factors. Instead, you should prefix each variable length piece of data to be sent with a fixed-length binary field containing the size. Then you need to ensure that you receive *exactly* the number of bytes sent at each point along the way. Otherwise, your data transfer is doomed to be unreliable.

Comment: @GilHamilton I guess I am a little confused, so you mean that for every "file" of unknown size, I should send a packet before the file containing the size of the incoming data? Or that I should append a packet-size to each packet? Because if you send a file size packet before every file, does it not still have the issue that we do not know the size of the "file-size packet"?

Comment: For example if I have a file size of 20 bytes that I am sending, I could describe the length of the file with a single byte sent before sending the file. But if I don't know how big the file will be, how do I know how many bytes to read in when I am getting this length variable?

Comment: If you're sending multiple files over the same connection you have to delimit them somehow, and you can't rely on an imagined equivalence between sends and receives to do that. So you have to have either a length-word prefix, a self-describing protocol like XML, or a file separator character, in which case you also have to have an escape protocol in case the separator or the escape character appears in the data.